# No module named MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql

I had mysql (in python) running in my laptop but after Yosemite was updated it stopped running.
I uninstall and install mysql again.

> pip install MySQL-python

added it to path:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

But still it doesn't work.

> import MySQLdb as mysql ImportError: No module named MySQLdb

Comment: what python version are you using 2.7 or 3.x? MySQLdb does not support Python 3

Comment: Try doing sudo pip install. If that doesn't work, do `xcode-select --install` and then do `sudo pip install`

Comment: PyMysql is the best alternative

Answer (score 0):

In case you get the error that Visual Studio is not installed on windows, you need to install precompiled MySQL-python from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5